# How to add POS tag feature in OpenNLP named entity recognition tool

Tags: opennlp, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to setup the OpenNLP NameFinder in a project with part-of-speech tag feature.
I extended my feature class from [FeatureGeneratorAdapter](http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.2-incubating/apidocs/opennlp-tools/opennlp/tools/util/featuregen/FeatureGeneratorAdapter.html) class, and overrode following method. Unfortunately this method taking just raw tokens in parameter. The problem is that how to pass POS tag information in to this method?

public void createFeatures(List features, String[] tokens, int index, String[] previousOutcomes)

Answer (score 0):

Try just passing in the pos as the tokens, ie append the pos to the word like this

bob_nn, went_vv etc....

the goal of the method in the interface is to return the "List features" ref back filled with the tokens so you may as well just put the pos_token combos straight into the list to begin with... never tried this before so hope this helps